# When to use print() vs close php

Tags: php, html

I want a few best practices among one of these methods, while combining HTML and PHP.

For example, not sure if in a template it's correct to do this:

```
if ($i == 0) { ?>
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
<?php } else { ?>
    <li role="presentation">
<?php } ?>
```

Or it's better:

```
if ($i == 0) {
    print('<li role="presentation" class="active"');
} else {
    print('<li role="presentation">');
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Personally i would say if it is only 1 line of html this doesn't makes a difference. If you have multiple lines of html i would definitively use the first one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply down to personal preference, really. There is no right or wrong answer.

Another option that I prefer is to use the following when breaking out of PHP and switching between markup and server code:

```
<?php if ($i == 0) : ?>
<li role="presentation" class="active">
<?php else : ?>    
<li role="presentation">
<?php endif ?>
```

Alternatively, you could use a Ternary Operator to keep things super-clean:

```
<li role="presentation"<?php echo ($i == 0) ? ' class="active"' : '' ?>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going for a clean approach you can try this:

```
<li role="presentation" <?php if ($i == 0) { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>>
```

If the condition returns true, then the li element will be assigned the class attribute of 'active'.

EDIT: A ternary operator is unnecessary in this case, as if the the condition does **not** return true the attribute will not be set.

Comment: You're right, a ternary operator is probably unnecessary, bit it's worth noting that it looks much cleaner, especially if there as a second class to be added in the case of  `$i != 0`.

Comment: @BenM Use of a ternary operator would be plausible if the OP was looking to assign the element to a different class if the statement returns false. In this case he doesn't appear to be so I was trying to direct my answer towards something he might be looking for. What you just stated holds a lot of truth though.